# Use VIM to step debug python like Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, vim, pydev

Is there a way to use vim to debug python programs and have it look/act somewhat like Eclipse with the PyDev plugin?

What I mean by that is:

- have it be able to step debug (is that the right term?)
- see the state all of all variables as the program executes
- be able to see where in the program the debug process is - maybe line highlighting?

I'm aware that Eclipse is a full featured IDE while VIM is a lightweight generic text editor (and that each comes with its own set of features) but I like being able to work in a console because I have a Windows 7 machine and typically use an Ubuntu Virtualbox to learn and work in python.

I have done some research and found the following things, but none of them seem to do all of what I want to above:

1. in a python program say import pdb then set a breakpoint in the code. This was line by line and didn't let me see the state of variables
2. gdb and Clewn. I couldn't get this setup, so if this is my answer just let me know and I'll dig deeper

If I misread the docs on either of the above also let me know and I'll dig back in.

Thanks!

Comment: use pdb `http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html`

Comment: @avasal does that integrate with vim?

Comment: pdb allows you with pts 1 & 2, you can also try this 'vimpdb': `http://code.google.com/p/vimpdb/` if you u like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote is for clewn, allthough I admit I haven't used it for python code. Just C, C++ code, but yes it worked like a charm.

If I remember correctly I even got this working, to a degree, on AIX 5.3 with dbx.

Comment: lolwut? AFAIR gdb works for python programs, so this seemed relevant. Downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I didn't, I appreciate the advice to use clewn. I'll see what I can do to get it integrated with vim

Answer (score 2):

[pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) is a variation of `clewn`, which was suggested by user [sehe](/users/85371/sehe).

From the webpage:

> Pyclewn allows using vim as a front end to a debugger. Pyclewn
>   currently supports gdb and pdb.